# Div tags are not visible after leaving mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, invisible

I'm working on a website that has a mobile version based on jquery. I want the user to be able to go to the orginal version from the mobile version, but when i use a link to the orginal version the div tags are invisible until i refresh the page.
How can i fix this?

Comment: How are they being hidden? Sounds it's via javascript and not css. You'll need to listen for window resize and ensure the elements become visible or use responsive css (best option)

Comment: Yes, they are being hidden by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to hide content at smaller screens. Otherwise, you need javascript resize event listeners to check if the screen size changes and then show your content. That's more work and performance drain than you want.